# Want to convert all datetimes in a nested dictionary to string and retain original dictionary as well

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

I want to convert all datetime (in key or in value) in a nested dictionary to string and retain original dictionary as well. In the below code I am not able to do so:

```
import datetime
import json


DATE_FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
def decode_dict(d):
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(key, (datetime.datetime,datetime.date)):
            key = datetime.datetime.strftime(key, DATE_FMT)
        if isinstance(value, (datetime.datetime,datetime.date)):
            value = datetime.datetime.strftime(value, DATE_FMT)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            value = decode_dict(value)  # Recursive call.
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for x,i in enumerate(value):
                if isinstance(i, (dict, list)):
                    decode_dict(i)
        result.update({key: value})
    return result


#This is the dictionary I want update.

item3 = {"vs": [{'Id': {
    'mval': datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 1, 0, 0),
    'vc': {datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 1, 0, 0): 1,
     datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 2, 0, 0): 1,
     datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 11, 0, 0): 1}}}]}

decode_dict(item3)

{'vs': [{'Id': {'mval': datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 1, 0, 0),
    'vc': {datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 1, 0, 0): 1,
     datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 2, 0, 0): 1,
     datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 11, 0, 0): 1}}}]}
```

Please guide here. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you observe?

Comment: Your function `decode_dict` returns the result. You need to assign that returned value to a variable

Comment: I see that for a nested dictionary it is failing for list. Added the output.